# Custom JSON validation constraints in Play Framework 2.3 (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework-2.3, playframework-json

I managed to implement form validation with custom constraints, but now I want to do the same thing with JSON data.

How can I apply custom validation rules to a JSON parser?

Example: The client's POST request contains a user name (`username`) and not only do I want to make sure that this parameter is a non-empty text, but also that this user actually exists in the database.

```
// In the controller...

def postNew = Action { implicit request =>
    request.body.asJson.map { json =>
        json.validate[ExampleCaseClass] match {
            case success: JsSuccess[ExampleCaseClass] =>
                val obj: ExampleCaseClass = success.get
                // ...do something with obj...
                Ok("ok")
            case error: JsError =>
                BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(error))
        }
    } getOrElse(BadRequest(Json.obj("msg" -> "JSON request expected")))
}


// In ExampleCaseClass.scala...

case class ExampleCaseClass(username: String, somethingElse: String)

object ExampleCaseClass {
    // That's what I would use for a form:
    val userCheck: Mapping[String] = nonEmptyText.verifying(userExistsConstraint)

    implicit val exampleReads: Reads[ExampleCaseClass] = (
        (JsPath \ "username").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "somethingElse").read[String]
    )(ExampleCaseClass.apply _)
}
```

That's as far as I get, but this only ensures that `username` is a String. **How do I apply my additional custom validation rule**, e.g. to check if the given user really exists? Is this even possible?

Sure, I could take my `obj` in the `case success` section in the action and perform additional checks there, but this doesn't seem very elegant, because then I'd have to create my own error message and could only user `JsError.toFlatJson(error)` for some cases. After searching and trying for hours I couldn't find any examples.

For regular forms I'd use something like this:

```
// In the controller object...

val userValidConstraint: Constraint[String] = Constraint("constraints.uservalid")({ username =>
    if (User.find(username).isDefined) {
        Valid
    } else {
        val errors = Seq(ValidationError("User does not exist"))
        Invalid(errors)
    }
})

val userCheck: Mapping[String] = nonEmptyText.verifying(userValidConstraint)

val exampleForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "username" -> userCheck
        // ...and maybe some more fields...
    )(ExampleCaseClass.apply)(ExampleCaseClass.unapply)
)


// In the controller's action method...

exampleForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest("Example error message")
    },
    formData => {
        // do something
        Ok("Valid!")
    }
)
```

But what if the data is submitted as JSON?

Comment: I would suggest validating your users after JSON validation. I think JSON validation is best used just to make sure you can get into Scala object land, and then everything else you need to do will be more comfortable from there on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would use the `filter` method from `Reads`.

Let's say we have some `User` object that will determine if the user name exists:

```
object User {
    def findByName(name: String): Option[User] = ...
}
```

You could then construct your `Reads` like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.data.validation._

case class ExampleCaseClass(username: String, somethingElse: String)

object ExampleCaseClass {
    implicit val exampleReads: Reads[ExampleCaseClass] = (
        (JsPath \ "username").read[String].filter(ValidationError("User does not exist."))(findByName(_).isDefined) and
        (JsPath \ "somethingElse").read[String]
    )(ExampleCaseClass.apply _)
}
```

Your controller function can be simplified using a json `BodyParser` and `fold`:

```
def postNew = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[ExampleCaseClass].fold(
        error => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(error)),
        obj => {
            // Do something with the validated object..
        }
    )
}
```

You could also create a separate `Reads[String]` that will check if the user exists, and explicitly use that `Reads[String]` within your `Reads[ExampleCaseClass]`:

```
val userValidate = Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("User does not exist."))(findByName(_).isDefined)

implicit val exampleReads: Reads[ExampleCaseClass] = (
    (JsPath \ "username").read[String](userValidate) and
    (JsPath \ "somethingElse").read[String]
)(ExampleCaseClass.apply _)
```

Comment: m-z the thing is that, if you use many validators like this, subsequent ones will still run if the previous one have failed. See this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077937/force-play-scala-json-composite-validators-to-fail-on-first-failed-validator

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida In general it is better to accumulate errors, rather than stop on the first (that is why the library is built that way). That is why I personally wouldn't use a JSON validator that makes a database call like this, and rather handle that elsewhere. But that's off topic to this question.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work if your findByName returns `Future` or DBIO (slick) which is more than likely. The play framework's validation API is not written to support Futures intentionally.