# Play Json Single Field Reads Validator

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to add simple validation to incoming Json in Play. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26317869/306149), I tried writing:

```
case class ApiData(data: String)

def maxLengthValidator = Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("Error"))(_.length < 100)

implicit val ApiDataReads: Reads[ApiData] = (
  (JsPath \ "data").read[String](maxLengthValidator)
)(ApiData.apply _)
```

This does not compile, producing the error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : String => ApiData
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[?]
[error]     )(ApiData.apply _)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
```

But if I add a second field, it does compile:

```
case class ApiData(data: String, __doNotUse: Option[Int])

implicit val ApiDataReads: Reads[ApiData] = (
  (JsPath \ "data").read[String](maxLengthValidator) and
  (JsPath \ "__doNotUse").readNullable[Int]
)(ApiData.apply _)
```

What do I need to do to get this working with just a single field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only have a single field, you don't need the combinator syntax to create a reads, you can just use the functions already defined on `Reads` to build the one you want.

```
def maxLengthValidator = Reads.of[String].filter(ValidationError("Error"))(_.length < 100)

case class ApiData(data: String)

object ApiData {

  implicit val reads: Reads[ApiData] = (__ \ "data").read(maxLengthValidator).map(ApiData.apply _)

}
```

You start with a `Reads[String]`, add some validation (`filter`) and then transform valid results to your own rich type (`map`).

Comment: Where is the path (`data`) coming from?