# Overloaded method value [read] cannot be applied to (String => SearchController.this.TrackSearch)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am querying the spotify api for a list of tracks for a given query using `ws`, when I come to transform the JSON data into a case class I'm getting an error that I've yet to figure out...

```
class SearchController @Inject() (
  val ws: WSClient
    ) extends Controller {

  case class TrackSearch(href: String)

  implicit val trackResultsReads: Reads[TrackSearch] = (
      (__ \ "tracks" \ "href").read[String]
    )(TrackSearch.apply _)

  def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
    search("track", param(request, "q")).map { r =>
       val ts = r.json.as[TrackSearch]
       println(ts)
       Ok
    }
  }

  private def search(category: String, query: String): Future[Try[WSResponse]] = {
    ws.url("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search")
      .withQueryString("q" -> query, "type" -> category)
      .get()
      .map(Success(_))
      .recover { case x => Failure(x) }
  }

  private def param(request: Request[AnyContent], name: String): String = {
    request.queryString.get(name).flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("")
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Overloaded method value [read] cannot be applied to  (String => SearchController.this.TrackSearch)

  implicit val trackResultsReads: Reads[TrackSearch] 
>    (__ \ "tracks" \ "href").read[String]
  )(TrackSearch.apply _)
```

If I query the JSPath in my action, I can get the "href" string back fine, so it is not that:

```
println(r._2.json \ "tracks" \ "href")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that there is just a single field. If you added a second field it would compile. I don't fully understand why it shouldn't compile with a single field. So in the single field case, try the following:

```
implicit val trackResultsReads: Reads[TrackSearch] = {
  ((__ \ "tracks" \ "href").read[String])
    .map(TrackSearch(_))
}
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/hGrveOkbJ6U) is quite an old link where I found the above. See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585503/play-json-single-field-reads-validator) for a similar SO question with a different approach.