# Force Play (Scala) Json Composite Validators to Fail on First Failed Validator

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm writing a custom validator for json objects.

The default method is to create a case class `T` and an implicit reader of type `Reads[T]`.

This is what my code looks like (I've created a simple "always fail" validator for the first json attribute just to illustrate my point).

(The second validator looks a bit different because I also need `"id"` to validate the `"body"`attribute, but I want to have it only run if the first one succeeds).

```
case class ExecuteQueryModel(datasourceId: Long, body: String)

object ExecuteQueryModel {
  def makeModel(id: Long, tpl: (Long, String)): ExecuteQueryModel = new ExecuteQueryModel(id, tpl._2)

implicit val reads: Reads[ExecuteQueryModel] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").read[Long](x => false) and
    (JsPath). read[(Long, String)](connectionDataIsValid("id", "qbody")))(ExecuteQueryModel.makeModel _)

}
```

My problem is that I want the whole validation to fail if the first validator fails, so that I can count on the ID being valid when I run the second validator.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance. I'm running play version **2.4.0**